# Ionic Framework saas fatal error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have changed nothing to my application, and the UI was created in the ionic GUI creator, but it still crashes when attempting to run `ionic serve`

Below is the error that I am getting:

```
[11:17:39]  sass: stdin, line: 1 
            File to import not found or unreadable: /var/lndFinal/src/theme/variables.scss. Parent style sheet: stdin 

[11:17:40]  dev server running: http://localhost:8100/ 

[OK] Development server running!
     Local: http://localhost:8100
     External: http://130.215.45.72:8100


[11:17:40]  Failed to open the browser: Command failed: xdg-open "http://localhost:8100" /bin/sh: 1: xdg-open: not found 
{ Error: A watch configured to watch the following paths failed to start. It likely that a file referenced does not exist: /var/lndFinal/src/assets/**/*, /var/lndFinal/src/index.html, /var/lndFinal/src/manifest.json, /var/lndFinal/src/service-worker.js, /var/lndFinal/node_modules/ionicons/dist/fonts/**/*, /var/lndFinal/node_modules/ionic-angular/fonts/**/*, /var/lndFinal/node_modules/ionic-angular/polyfills/polyfills.js, /var/lndFinal/node_modules/sw-toolbox/sw-toolbox.js
    at new BuildError (/var/lndFinal/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/util/errors.js:16:28)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/var/lndFinal/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/watch.js:71:20)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:471:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:306:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:266:5) hasBeenLogged: false, isFatal: false }
```

The file to import error at path: `/var/lndFinal/src/theme/variables.scss` doesn't exist, and neither do the other files being pointed at in the error.  Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being that the original src directory generated using just a simple `ionic start appName blank` had the config files in them.  The UI src folder exported from the Ionic GUI creator does not have the config files (It also doesn't support the `theme` files in the `src` directory yet for version 3).

Steps: 
1. Before importing new src UI folder, move all config and .js files to the main application folder
2. Move the `theme` folder from `src` to the main application folder as well.
3. Overwrite the `src` folder with the new UI `src` folder
4. Move the `theme` folder back into the `src` folder

Should be all set now!